# R Shiny Using Deprecated Bootstrap

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am building a Shiny app and have been looking into editing the bootstrap themes.

I am using the latest version of Shiny (0.9.1), which I have noticed uses bootstrap version 2.3.2 (see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/bootstrap.R)), which is deprecated (see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)).

Among other changes, version 3 of bootstrap has integrated the bootstrap-responsive.css into bootstrap.css, and the same for the .min files.

Is there a way of forcing Shiny to use the latest bootstrap?  I'm rolling the app across different machines and a Linux server, so would like to minimise custom changes which could break elsewhere.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is on our plan, but I have no idea when it will be done at the moment...

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if there is any news on Bootstrap 3 in Shiny?  Thanks for all your work!

Comment: It is available in the development version now. Thank Winston Chang instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shiny [will use Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/611) after version 0.10.2.2. For now, you can try the development version: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny